# how to structure iterating through a list based on a condition in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am reading a PDF and saving elements to a list. I need to get names and dates using regular expressions. I'm good with regex but wondering about how to logic this.

As I iterate through a list (each element is a line in the PDF) I have something like this:

| Some Section Name |  |
| --- | --- |
| name a | date |
| name b | date |
| name c | date |
| name d | date |
| Next Section Name |  |

Right now I can do this to find the section:

```
if re.match("^Some Section Name", line, re.IGNORECASE):
    do something to get names and dates
```

But the number of names may not be the same.

The names have font size 9pt so I can use that in the "while", and the Next Section is 18pt. Putting that together, how can I implement the "while" part of this logic to save names and dates until the font size changes?

```
for line in page:
    if re.match("^Some Section Name", line, re.IGNORECASE):
        while(names and dates with font size 9pt):
            save names and dates until the Next Section
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the font size is a red herring, because you already have a way to detect the section header lines. Since those contain no data, you just ignore them and let the loop run over the remaining lines to save your data:

```py
for line in page:
    if not re.match("^Some Section Name", line, re.IGNORECASE):
        # save name and date from this line
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
for line in page:
if re.match("^Some Section Name", line, re.IGNORECASE):
    while(names and dates):
        if fontsize != 9t:
            break;

        save names and dates until the Next Section
```